# Content Security Policy blocking images from installed plugins' popup info window, as they are from external domains - global fix?

Tags: security, headers

I have Content Security Policy added to my WordPress site via `Header set` in `.htaccess`, and just found if I am on the WordPress plugins admin page (/wp-admin/plugins.php), and click "View Details" for any given plugin, its images in its popup are blocked. They come from an all external domains, none of which are allowed in my CSP (although it's possible there could be some overlap from another item or site function, but most if not all are not).

Do I have to add the `url` to `img-src` in my CSP for *every* plugin's "View Details" popup window, or is there a way to use CSP to say "images from any now or future installed plugin's view details window are allowed to load"? I am assuming I have to add each manually, and add new ones if a new plugin is installed - but wanted to check around from others first!

Also - if I should have asked this in one of the other Stack forums, please let me know!

Thanks[image: Screenshot showing this and console errors]

Comment: I think Stack Overflow is probably the better place, so I posted this there also. There I could use the tag content-security-policy whereas here, the tag does not exist. [Here is the same question posted on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559630/content-security-policy-blocking-images-from-installed-plugins-popup-info-windo)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/263477)

Comment: You only need to add the domain, so just allow images from ps.w.org and any plugins hosted on wordpress.org should be fine.

Comment: tag creation is something that comes when you have higher reputation, and you'll need to include what you did to your HTAccess for an answer to be possible. It's also very possible that what you want to do is fundamentally incompatible with underscores templating making it impossible without crippling Yoast SEO and the media library, but I can only guess at the changes you made to CSP. Note that CSP is one of the few ways you can permanently make a domain name unusable for websites if you mess up badly enough

Comment: Also this isn't a forum!! I converted your "solution" into a comment, the answer box is for answers/solutions, they aren't replies like a forum and they move as people vote up and down

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you for the comments and helping me do things right here. I posted an answer that is more of an answer and less of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as mentioned in a comment by @JacobPeattie, was to add the domains to my `.htaccess` file where I am setting the CSP Headers, (turns out *most* plugins' "View Details" link loads images from ps.w.org, which I just learned). A few other plugins loaded images from other domains, so I also added each of those domain(s) to my `.htaccess` as well. This looks like:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy: img-src 'self' https://ps.w.org/ https://updates.theme-fusion.com/wp-content/uploads/
```

And so on (I didn't list all the other domains, just one to show as example. Now all the plugins' "View Details" images load without error as they are listed in the CSP.